# Remove/hide text with css

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a `p` and I want to remove/hide the first two letters. Is there any way I can do that with only CSS (no JS)?

Example:

```css
.remove-letters {
  /* STYLES-HERE */
}
```

```html
<p class="remove-letters">yrHello There!</p>
```

Comment: Not really, because you have no way of knowing how _wide_ these first two letters will actually render, unless a monospace font was used. `overflow:hidden` plus `text-indent: -...` would otherwise do the trick, if you knew what pixel or em/rem value to insert for the `...` part.

Comment: since there is only a `:first-letter` and not a `:nth-letter()` selector you will need JS. Theoretically you can do it with a negative margin on the `<p>` element but this will only help you aslong as you only have 1 line.

Comment: @tacoshy i thoug the same with negative margin but im sure that is a hacky solution because some chars have different width.

Comment: you could try putting that 2 letters in another div and then use the property .remove-letters:hover {  display: none; }   so when ever you hover it will dissapear. but thats not what you want. soo practlicly with no JS you cant really do that..

Comment: @MaikLowrey not with monospace. There every char has a width of `1ch`.

Comment: @tacoshy How do you know which font the questioner uses? but yes with monospace would maybe possible. but that is nevertheless  not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do this in pure css! It uses the `ch` font-dependent unit.

```css
.remove-letters {
font-family: monospace;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display:block;
text-indent: -2ch;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p class="remove-letters">yrHello There!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this works only with **monospace fonts** and not in older browsers.

Comment: Great! Any why, out of curiosity; can you please share why you need such CSS code? Can you give example?

Comment: However it should be noted as siad already in the comments that this only works for a 1 line text. If you have multiple lines it will not work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Without Javascript you cant achieve this very well. It would be a very hacky solution. With JS would be working like a charm.

```js
let str = "yrHello There!"
console.log(str.substring(2))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a way to do it...

Example:

```css
.remove-letters {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.remove-letters:after {
  font-size: 10px;
  content: "Hello There!";
}
```

```html
<p class="remove-letters">yrHello There!</p>
```

Comment: Sure, but this hardcodes the desired content inside the CSS. It may solve your problem but it doesn't answer your question ;)

Comment: That is true. I think it's impossible to do it with css. It does the job tho.

Comment: CSS should really come out with some substring method...

Comment: ehh no?  CSS is for styling. you are completely missing the point of it

Comment: Yeah true. That's what JS is for...

Comment: I am quite confused with the goal here. Since this is super hardcoded, why not just edit the HTML and remove the "yr" prefix?

Comment: It's just out of curiosity...

Comment: ok, that makes sense! it's good to try out things like that you gain a deeper understanding of things. good for you @olifire